# Database log reduce max size (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql-server, database, logging

Are there any downsides to reducing the log to 4 MB instead of the default 2097152?

When the database log reaches the max size of 4 MB, what happens?

Is the log cleaned (truncated to 1MB) and open for refilling? Until the max size of 4 MB is reached, once again?

[image]

Comment: If you limit it to 4Mb, any operation that should write >= 2Mb to the log WILL FAIL

Comment: Get error "transaction log is full"